# Outline bugging when quickly entering and leaving mouse

Tags: lua, roblox

so I want to make a script where if you hover the mouse on a part it will get a outline but when you take it off it will disappear, but if you spam the function by entering and leaving the mouse on the part, the part either remains with the outline or without, or even flickering when entering mouse, so I added a db, but that didn t really work.

If you think you could help I would appreciate it.

Here is the script:

```
local part = script.Parent
local db = false

part.ClickDetector.MouseHoverEnter:Connect(function()
    if db == true then
        return
    else
        db = true
        repeat
            part.Highlight.OutlineTransparency = part.Highlight.OutlineTransparency - 0.5
            wait(0.05)
        until part.Highlight.OutlineTransparency <= 0
        wait(0.1)
        db = false
    end
end)

part.ClickDetector.MouseHoverLeave:Connect(function()
    if db == true then
        return
    else
        db = true
        repeat
            part.Highlight.OutlineTransparency = part.Highlight.OutlineTransparency + 0.5
            wait(0.05)
        until part.Highlight.OutlineTransparency >= 1
        wait(0.1)
        db = false
    end
end)
```